# Sum and radius of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\cos(5n)+i \sin(5n))z^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I calculated radius and sum of the series in the title. First i converted that in the exponential form: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{i5n}z^{n}$ then I applied the ratio test and i got a value of $e^{i5}$ for the ray (complex??) and i saw a geometric serie for the sum, getting $\frac{1}{1-e^{i5}z}$. Am I proceeding correctly?

Comment: Does your sum even converge (I don't think so)? Do you have a conjecture where it'd converge to?

Comment: Hint $$\sum e^{i(2n+1)}=0$$

Comment: I was wrong. I'll correct the text

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, why is that? Can you link to a proof?

Comment: $|e^{i \varphi}|=1$ for all $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1):

We have the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{5ni}z^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(e^{5i}z\right)^n$$

Apply the $\;n$-th root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{|e^{5i}z|^n}=|e^{5i}||z|=|z|$$

So the series converges for $\;|z|<1\;$ and now you can use the general expression for the sum of a convergent geometric series .